# Github checkout from Jenkins fails since iptables config

Tags: iptables

Yesterday I added some rules to iptables so that people can't access to my server through any port they want. I may have made something wrong, because today some Jenkins jobs doing checkouts from Github don't work anymore. I also noticed that `wget` doesn't work anymore, but `ping` still does.

Do I need to add specific ports to allow Github to send me the code back, or did I do something wrong when I added the iptables rules ? Basically I used the following commands :

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --dport 10000:65535 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s 0/0 --dport 10000:65535 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j DROP`

Answer (score 0):

Does removing these two lines from your iptables fix the problem? Git uses port 9418. Your rules don't seem to apply to git.

Verify that these lines in your iptables are indeed what is blocking git by removing them and retesting.

Also remove the -s 0/0 and try again.